# python scrapy stop scrapy when a condition happened

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to extract all the data from a website.

I am using scrapy 0.20.2

My code is

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    start_urls = ['TheWebsite']
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/?page=\d+']), 'parse')]

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = sel.xpath('MyXPath')
        for site in sites:
            if condition < 8:
                yield Request(Link, meta = {'date': Date},\
                   callback = self.MyFunction)
            else:
                # Code to stop scrapy goes here.
```

the crawler will scrapy all the data from the url that has this syntax:

```
Mywebsite?page=INTEGER
```

but when a specific condition happened, I want to stop crawling. In my code I want to do that when the `else` happened. How please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exit the `for` loop at that point, use `break`:

```
for site in sites:
    if condition < 8:
        # ...
    else:
        break
```

This will put you outside the `for` loop and therefore exit `parse`. If you need to send a value back, rather than implicitly `return None`, you can `return` instead of `break`, which will also exit the function. `break` also allows you to have further code in your function:

```
for ...:
    if something:
        break
# do something else before finishing
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`break`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) to terminate `for` loop or use [`return`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) statement to leave the function.

```
for site in sites:
    if condition < 8:
        yield Request(Link, meta={'date': Date}, callback = self.MyFunction)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: will that prevent the starts-Url from continuing scraping please? or just leave the for loop ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, It terminates the `for` loop => cause no more `yield Request` => prevent additional scarping to occur.

Comment: but please look at the starts_url. will it keep scrawling even if the else happened please? also, kindly check the `+d` isn't means that `?page=1` and `?page=2` ...ets ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, Ah... `/?` should be `\?` to match `?` literally, because `?` has a special meaning in regular expression.

Comment: i will tell you all the business logic. i have a website for millions of pages. each page have ads. i want to scrap on all ads that have been added in the last 7 days. so i make the url for scraping on each page that have the syntax `?page=2`, then i check the date of that page. if it is less than 7 days. i scrap on all the contents on a new function. if not i want to exit the scraper. i am doing wrong with code pelase?